# Método Async retornando um List<string> como utilizar?

Tags: c#, winforms, lista, async

Tenho um método chamado `consulta_usuario_email`, que é responsável por buscar na tabela de usuários cadastrados, os emails dos usuários de certo departamento:

```
 public async Task<List<string>> consulta_usuario_email(string departamento)
    {
        consql.bd_string();
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);

        List<string> email = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            consql._sql = @"select a.Email
                            from AspNetUsers as a
                            left join Empresa_departamento as c
                            on a.Departamento = c.id
                            where c.departamento = @departamento";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@departamento", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = departamento;

            await sqlconn.OpenAsync();

            using (SqlDataReader leitor = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (leitor.Read())
                {
                    email.Add(leitor["Email"].ToString());
                }
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro" + "\n" + error);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlconn.Close();
        }

        return email;
    } // consulta o email do usuario conforme seu departamento
```

Quero executar esse método `Async`, e então quando este estiver concluído, quero executar outro método que recebe como parâmetros o `List` gerado pelo método `consulta_usuario_email`

```
 Task<List<string>> Mail_PCP = Email_User.consulta_usuario_email("PCP");

          if (Mail_PCP.IsCompleted == true)
          {
              Mail_Urgente.Send(Mail_Compras, Mail_PCP, "Teste", "Teste");
          }
```

Porem, como faço para passar o `List` para o método `Send` da classe `Mail_Urgente`?

Atualização - ref. a resposta do colaborador @LINQ:

> "É só usar await, assim:"
>
> ```
> List<string> Mail_PCP = await Email_User.consulta_usuario_email("PCP");
> Mail_Urgente.Send(Mail_Compras, Mail_PCP, "Teste", "Teste");
> ```

Ao tentar fazer conforme acima é gerado o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só usar `await`, assim.

```
List<string> Mail_PCP = await Email_User.consulta_usuario_email("PCP");
Mail_Urgente.Send(Mail_Compras, Mail_PCP, "Teste", "Teste");
```

Lembre que o método que chama o `consulta_usuario_email` precisa ser marcado com `async`.

Você pode testar isso com este código:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public async static void Main()
    {
        var lista = await TaskTeste();      
        lista.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);       
    }

    public async static Task<List<string>> TaskTeste()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => (new List<string> { "LINQ", "teste" }));
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vRFLES)

Comment: amigo, mas assim é gerado um erro... fiz uma revisão na pergunta adicionando uma foto do erro.

Comment: Não vejo nenhum erro.

Comment: acabei de atualizar a pergunta

Comment: O erro é autoexplicativo. Tem que marcar o método chamado com `async`.

Comment: Mas o método `consulta_usuario_email` ja esta marcado como `Async` como pode ser visto no começo da pergunta.

Comment: O **método chamador** precisa ser marcado como `async`. Foi erro de digitação meu.

Comment: Perfeito. entendi. Obrigado.